# JavaScript if statement evaluates only first condition

Tags: javascript

My if statement evaluates only 1st condition, second one after || is overlooked. How to fix this?

```
function validateAge(input) {
  if ((input.value < 0 || input.value > 110) || (input.value.match(/[^0-9]/))) {
    input.setCustomValidity("Dozwolony zakres: od 0 do 110");
  } else {
    input.setCustomValidity("");
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `input.value`? Because if `input.value < 0` gives `true`, then it doesn't need any other expression.

Answer (score 7):

Well, there is something called [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). The JavaScript interpreter won't evaluate something if it is unnecessary to do so. In the disjunction (`||`) when the first statement evaluates to `true` then the whole expression is true, so that's why when the JavaScript interpreter evaluates: `(input.value < 0 || input.value > 110)` to true, it is not necessary to calculate the value of `(input.value < 0 || input.value > 110)`.

If `(input.value.match(/[^0-9]/))` is "show stopper" you can proceed the following way:

```
if ((input.value.match(/[^0-9]/)) || (input.value < 0 || input.value > 110))
```

If I understood correctly you need something like:

```
function validateValue(input) {
  var value = input.value;
  if (/^\d+$/.test(value)) {
    value = parseInt(value, 10);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  return value < 0 || value > 110;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. But it seems that the regex is not working. When I input for instance a letter it goes through (and it should print the message). I tried to paste some ready-made number regex but they failed too. What could cause the problem?

Comment: What is the purpose of the regex? It should pass only numbers or?

Comment: The form field should accept only numbers from 0-9 and value range from 0 to 110. If a user inputs letter or a sign it should prompt the message (Valid range: From 0 to 110)

Comment: Change your regex to `/^\d+$/`

Comment: Just posted a function which may solve your problem.

Comment: I can still input a letter and no message is prompted with the regex you provided. Weird thing

Comment: You're doing something wrong: `/^\d+$/.test('13a')` how can this be evaluated to `true`? Use the validation function I provided you above.